# Error when running pod update for the second time with cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

coming across an error when running cocoapods. I successfully ran `pod update` with no issues. Then ran the Swift 3.0 migrate assistant. There are a few pods I now want to remove from my project. I have commented them out of the pod file but when I run `pod update` again I get the following error:

```
Errno::EEXIST - File exists - /Users/myname/Documents/MyProj/MyProj Dev/ios-app/Pods/Target Support Files/AMPopTip
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer.rb:92:in `mkdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer.rb:92:in `mkdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer.rb:92:in `create_support_files_dir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:21:in `block in install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:19:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:153:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:153:in `block in install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:152:in `install_libraries'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:64:in `generate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:179:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:115:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:60:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated! Thanks!